# Google Sheets – ImportHTML: Select span inside a table td

Tags: google-sheets, html-table, google-finance

**Google Sheets – ImportHTML - select span inside a table data cell**

I would like to select a **span** inside a table data cell `<td>` using `=ImportHTML` function in Google Spreadsheet.

I could successfully select the table `<td>` I need:
`=Index(ImportHTML("https://www.example.com/page/","table",1),3,4)`

**But** this `<td>` contains a span and small element and I would like to **extract the number inside the span** – which would be "5432.34" in this example (if possible without thousands separator "**'**"):

```html
<td>
<span class="price_in_table_colored">5'432.34</span> 
<small>USD </small>
</td>
```

How can I get this to work? I couldn't figure out how to get this working.
XML path would be following:

```xml
//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span

//or in full: 
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/span
```